# Temperature Density

Tags: temperature, field-theory, density

Say we have some scalar field over space, say temperature. Let's say it varies as $1/x$, where $x$ is distance from the origin. Is there any way to define a temperature density over a certain volume in that space?

Comment: How would you deal with the singularity at the origin?

Answer (score 1):

From a physical standpoint it makes sense to define density for extensive quantities (mass, energy, momentum...) but temperature is intensive.

If $T=T(x)$ and the energy $U=U(T)$ is function of $T$, then we can write
$$
   C_V 
  = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)
  = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\right)
    \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial T}\right)
$$
from which
$$
   \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\right)
   = 
   C_V \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right)
$$
Here, the left-hand side is the density of energy per unit length and its integral over $x$ is the total energy in a region of $x$.

The right-hand side involves the derivative $\partial T/\partial x$, which *mathematically* you might call density of temperature. However, its integral over $x$, while mathematically sound, has no physical meaning because there is no such thing as "total temperature" within a region of space.